# Which Geotools jar contains the "Encoder" class?

Tags: maven, maven-2, geotools

I am trying to export a JTS object to a KML file. I found [here](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/xsd/kml.html#kml-encoding) that this could be done using the `Encoder` class, however I can't seem to find the jar file that contains the given class.

I am using maven, adding a repository is not an option, I must have all the jars used in the company repository so I would like to install the specific jar as a maven artifact manually.

I looked on the [Geotools repository](http://repo.opengeo.org/org/geotools/), in `org/geotools/xml/9.3/gt-xml` and in `org/geotools/xml/9.3/gt-xsd-kml` but I didn't find it.

Please help me.

Comment: maven should pull them in automatically - can you post your pom file?

Comment: I didn't think of adding the third-party repository locally because all the jars should be available in our company repository. I did this now, and I still had to do a little bit of guessing, but I finally found it. Thanks @iant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found it. The class is in `gt-xsd-core.jar`. The required maven dependency is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools.xsd</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-xsd-core</artifactId>
    <version>9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I also needed the `KMLConfiguration` class, which I found in `gt-xsd-kml.jar`. The required dependency is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools.xsd</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-xsd-kml</artifactId>
    <version>9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: isn't that imported by <dependency>
  <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
  <artifactId>gt-xml</artifactId>
  <version>${geotools.version}</version>
</dependency>

Comment: No, it isn't. Now I have a problem finding the class org.geotools.kml.KMLConfiguration. I've imported gt-xml, gt-xsd-core, gt-xsd-fes, gt-xsd-filter, gt-xsd-ows, gt-xsd-wfs, gt-xsd-gml3, but none of them contains it.

Comment: can you do mvn dependency:tree

Comment: I did find it in http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/org/geotools/gt2-xml-kml/, but this only has a milestone release and I would need a stable release.

Comment: you also seem to be mixing releases (2.7.5 v 9.x in the Q)

Comment: mvn dependency:tree added to the answer. Yes, in the question I asked for the latest release, but the geotools repository gave me jars for 2.7.5, which is fine as long as I can find all the required jars.

Comment: 2.7 is very old - please try maven tree for 9.x

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32395/discussion-between-zoltan-and-iant)

Comment: Yes, switching to 9.3 solved all my problems. For some reason m2eclipse failed to list version 9.3 through the add dependency wizard. After I changed the version manually, everything worked fine. I updated the answer accordingly. Thanks a lot @iant.